# Is a network shield required to do POSTGET requests with arduino?

Tags: post, networking, get, arduino, nfc

By means of being thorough i was wondering if someone could tell me if I need an ethernet/wifi shield to be able to use POSTGET requests using my arduino.

I've got an NFC shield and I need to send the data stored on the tag to my web server.

Comment: Ok, just a hint: don't apologize beforehand. How do you plan to communicate with your web server?

Comment: In fact, I'll go ahead and remove your apologies and self-loathing from the question. It's easier to read then.

Comment: lol thanks, i haven't posted much here so just wanted to play it safe. I've got an apache tomcat web server and a java servlet, the plan is for the user to go to the web page, scan their nfc tag, and for the id from that tag to be sent to my web server for handling via a doPost method

Comment: nono, I mean how do you plan to *physically* make the arduino contact your web sever?

Comment: Well...i guess that may answer my question lol. I guess i thought that since the arduino sketch is on my pc, which is on a network, that i'd be able to take the info received from the tag and just ship it off, with nothing but the included usb

Comment: ah, so you've got a PC connected to your Arduino!

Comment: I don't know, sounds like you could use the USB connection to communicate with your PC, to make it contact the web server.

Comment: That would be ideal. I guess i'll just give it a shot and try it. But I wonder what libraries to use, since the ones I've found so far all mention having an ethernet shield

Comment: Well, you wouldn't implement the web server communication on the arduino -- just some kind of data communication with your PC, that would then run a simple program that issues your HTTP requests.

Comment: Oh I see. I actually just found a post on the arduino forums that mentions doing just that (he mentions just using a shield would be easier though). But, for the sake of this question I suppose we've come to a conclusion, that being that I can't do it directly, but i can fake it by passing the data onto someone that can. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can't do it directly, but if you're planning to use USB, you can
>   send data using the various serial commands to the PC you're connected
>   to. You'll need a program written in your language of choice on the PC
>   listening to the arduino and that program can submit your GET request
>   for you.
>
> Or in other words, you can fake it, but an ethernet capability would
>   probably be better & easier.

Copied from a post I found in the Arduino forums